# Why does php: losing utf-8 after preg_replace call?

Tags: php, utf-8

Here is my code:

```
$source = preg_replace('/<table  align="center">(.*)<\/html>/s', '', $source );
file_put_contents('source1.html', $source); // source1 is GOOD : contains UTF-8

$source = preg_replace('/<html>.*<center>/sU', '', $source );
file_put_contents('source2.html', $source); // source2 is BAD: contains some ðåùàéí
```

- The first preg_replace keeps utf-8 chars (hebrew chars)
- The second preg_replace replaces all these chars by some ðåùàéí chars

Any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

Try use `mb_internal_encoding("UTF-8");`

Comment: Using that method, I got some ����� chars !

Comment: Couldn't it be caused by same variable name which is given to `preg_replace` and where is then stored their result?

Comment: I tried with:

$source2 = preg_replace('/<html>.*<center>/sU', '', $source );
file_put_contents('source2.html', $source2); // source2 is BAD: contains some ðåùàéí